# XPath cutting off href attribute

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm having some problems using XPath with Scrapy.

I'm looking at links in a table - in the browser, it lists the full link when viewing the element. However, scrapy shell is cutting off the end of the link.

Example link from table:

```
    http://www.ashp.org/DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=463
```

When inspecting element:

```
    <a href="/DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=463">
```

Extracting in scrapy shell removes the 463.

Any ideas?

Here's the code for the spider. Haven't actually set it up to crawl through the links yet, I figured I'd get everything set up with correct XPath syntax first.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from ashp.items import AshpItem

    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "ashp"
    allowed_domains = ["ashp.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://ashp.org/menu/DrugShortages/CurrentShortages"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        for titles in titles:
            title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            print title, link
```

Comment: Could you show the code of the spider?

Comment: EDIT: Removed code from comment, thanks

Comment: post it in your code! not in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your xpath is not correct. Here's a spider that prints all `Bulletin` links on the page:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "ashp"
    allowed_domains = ["ashp.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://ashp.org/menu/DrugShortages/CurrentShortages"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select("//div[@id='Mid_3Col']/div/table/tr/td/a")
        for link in links:
            title = link.select("text()").extract()[0]
            link = link.select("@href").extract()[0]
            print title, link
```

Output:

```
Acetazolamide Injection /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=463 
Acetylcysteine Inhalation Solution /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=932 
Acyclovir Injection /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=467 
Adenosine Injection /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=976 
Alcohol Dehydrated Injection (Ethanol) /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=778 
Allopurinol Injection /DrugShortages/Current/Bulletin.aspx?id=998
...
```

Comment: That gave the desired output, thanks!

I'm still a little confused on the problem I was having. I was using the scrapy shell to test different outputs - even after updating my spider and crawling successfully, the output in scrapy shell still cuts off the id number.

Any idea why? Maybe it has something to do with the encoding? The scrapy documentation I was following (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector) mentioned that hxs.select().extract returns a unicode string, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @user2758955 cannot really say what was the problem. I've tried your version of spider but it didn't actually crawled anything, i.e. `titles` was an empty list.

Comment: Does the spider matter when you're just testing the Xpath in the  shell? 

I used your Xpath, and even tried looking at just //@href

Not hugely important, just curious for learning purposes

Comment: Yup, you can test xpaths in the scrapy's shell. By the way, the reason your xpaths wasn't working is because there is no `span` with `pl` class on the page.